# Troubleshoot ssh prompting for password

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and I am having trouble to login through ssh without password although I added my ssh keys. It was working before and then suddenly stopped working. I do not know what I did exactly to make it stop working. Could you help me troubleshoot this? Is there a way to reset everything and start from the beginning?

While trying to fix it, I run several times but without success the following 2 commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id myusername@remotehost
```

Now in the remote machine when i do:

```
cat authorized_keys
```

It gives me three keys.

And in the client machine:
Here are the permisions that I have for .ssh folder:

```
drwx------  2 user user    4096 Apr 18 09:44 .ssh
```

And here are the permissions inside that folder:

```
-rw------- 1 user user  822 Apr 15 13:08 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 user user 1679 Apr 18 09:44 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  411 Apr 18 09:44 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2335 Apr 14 16:06 known_hosts
```

Here is the verbose outpout:

```
$ ssh -v user@localhost
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/CGAtknCe0ao9c+ZRoBDrbdBEaoweEKCtN0r+gO9Nyg
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I just noticed this and home it gonna be a hint for something:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
42  debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279      42  debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
43  debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa      43  debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
44  debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa        44  debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
45  debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519      45  debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

I do not have these files in my .ssh folder here is what i have:

```
-rw------- 1 user user 1233 Apr 18 12:31 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 user user 1679 Apr 18 09:44 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  411 Apr 18 09:44 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2335 Apr 14 16:06 known_hosts
```

Thanks

Comment: Post server and client verbose logs to see the reason for rejecting the key.

Comment: @Jakuje, I updated with verbose output. It seems that it fails using the private key. I am not sure if I modify it by error. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Bump `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `sshd_config` on server, restart `sshd` service and check the logs from the login. It should tell you the reason why the key is rejected.

Comment: Do you have a passphrase on your key?

Comment: @Jakuje, I added the output to the ticket

Comment: @andrew.46, no I do not

Comment: @KarimMtl no, you posted the client logs again. Server logs are in `/var/log/auth.log` or so.

Comment: Do you run this as the user that you mention before @localhost?

Comment: @Jakuje: I updated with the server logs

Comment: Your key is accepted, but not as a whole authentication. What do you have in your `sshd_config`?

Comment: @Jajuke: What are the settings in sshd_config that you are doubting are causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is kind of extreme, but solved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove openssh-client openssh-server
```

Then rename my .ssh folder, and started from scratch. this fixed the problem from my localhost connection as well as other remote servers I am using. I had obviously to copy the public key to all machines.

Thanks